# docker-compose env file set by command line

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

So i want to use a custom env file depends on a custom enviroment variable passed via command line.

Let's say that i start my compose with docker-compose run command:

```
docker-compose run -e ENVIROMENT=local spring-app
```

then i want to use my custom .env in my docker-compose.yml file based on ENVIROMENT variable

```
version: '2.1'
services:

  spring-app:
    build: .
      depends_on:
        docker-mariadb:
          condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - docker-mariadb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
      - DATABASE_HOST
      - DATABASE_USER
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD
      - DATABASE_NAME
      - DATABASE_PORT
    env_file:
      - ${ENVIROMENT}.env

  docker-mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    healthcheck:
      test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=${DATABASE_USER} --password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD} --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    env_file:
      - ${ENVIROMENT}.env
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:10-jre-slim
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE="build/libs/spring-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
COPY ${JAR_FILE} spring-app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/spring-app.jar"]
```

local.env:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
DATABASE_HOST=docker-mariadb
DATABASE_USER=root
DATABASE_PASSWORD=xxx
DATABASE_NAME=xxx
DATABASE_PORT=3306
```

When i run this command my custom ENVIROMENT variable seems not to be set and docker still want to use default .env file.
This is my error:

```
❯ docker-compose run -e ENVIROMENT=local spring-app
WARNING: The ENVIROMENT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DATABASE_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DATABASE_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DATABASE_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: Couldn't find env file: /Users/user/Desktop/docker-example/.env
```

Comment: You are still referring 

```
    env_file:
      - ${ENVIROMENT}.env
```

in docker compose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-e` flag is meant to pass the environment variables to the container. Add your environment before your `docker run` command to assign the environment variable to the docker engine so that the environment variable interpolation can be done

```
docker-compose run -e ENVIROMENT=local spring-app
[...]
ERROR: Couldn't find env file: /Users/sabhat/code/scratch/.env
```

---

```
ENVIROMENT=local docker-compose run spring-app
[...]
Starting scratch_docker-mariadb_1
```

As an aside, hope you are aware that `docker-compose run` is meant to [run a one-time command for a service](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) - and it doesn't map the ports and also overrides the run commands defined in the service. You should be using [`docker-compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) to bring up the entire set of containers