# How to pass environment variable to Docker Compose using CLI

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that adds `--reload.data=${RELOAD}` to an `ENTRYPOINT` in Dockerfile.

```
services:
    app:
        build: .
        image: app:1.0.0
        command: --reload.data=${RELOAD}
```

The value of `${RELOAD}` is in `.env` file. So if I want to set this value to `true`, I would just edit it there. However, I'm not entirely satisfied with this approach. Is there a way to pass an environment variable into `docker-compose` but within commandline?

For example:

```
docker-compose up -e RELOAD=true
```

Comment: You should be able to use any normal Bourne shell approach to set the environment variable, _e.g._ `RELOAD=true docker-compose up`.

Comment: Please try searching before posting a new question.  Sarching for your exact title turns up many answers here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49293967/how-to-pass-environment-variable-to-docker-compose-up, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72594538/pass-environment-variable-in-docker-compose-up-command, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73280477/how-to-set-docker-compose-yaml-environment-variable-from-a-shell-output, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974044/docker-compose-env-file-set-by-command-line ...

Comment: @DavidMaze Hi, thanks. At first, I was trying this command on Windows's CMD and was wondering why it didn't work. Then, you've mentioned Bourne shell and it indeed does works!

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for the links and sorry for creating duplicates. I admit that I've searched for my issue before posting a new question, but did not receive these entries in response. I might have used a wrong query.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .env file:

`RELOAD=true`

And then use the command:

`docker-compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev up`

Hope it works!

[Ways to set environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/)

Comment: Hi, this is not what I was looking for. I aim for having the `RELOAD=true` key-pair argument to be specified *directly* in the commandline interface. I do not want to have `.env` file involved at all. @DavidMaze gave a solution to my problem in the comment to the original post.